# Excess elements in scalar initializer

Tags: c++, stl

(Updated with more code details)

I'm pretty noobish when it comes to C++ STL stuff.

After a compiler (LLVM GCC 4.2) upgrade, I'm getting:

```
error: Semantic Issue: Excess elements in scalar initializer
```

on the call:

```
Certificate *tempcert;
certMap cm;

cm.insert( cValType( tempcert->id, tempcert ) );
```

with a typedef of:

```
typedef std::map< string, certificate* > certMap;
typedef std::map< string, certificate* >::value_type cValType;
```

I'm not certain what this error is telling me or how to fix it.  (Ok, I realize it's telling me excess elements, but it looks like it matches the map prototype to me, so I'm confused.)

Suggestions?

Comment: Your error doesn't match your code. `cValType(tempPerson->name, tempcert)` creates a temporary variable of type `std::pair<string, certificate *>` and then destructs it again - there's neither scalars nor initializers involved.

Comment: Updated with more code details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the confusion around this question was caused by buggy error messages in Xcode 4.

After replacing a shared library generating errors (which were below the error in question), the error went away.